# Select data with Join

Tags: sql, postgresql, postgresql-9.3, postgresql-9.4

I want to select rows from the table with the same ID.

```
   CREATE TABLE ACCOUNT(
 ID INTEGER NOT NULL,
 USER_NAME TEXT NOT NULL,
 PASSWD TEXT,
 FIRST_NAME TEXT,
 LAST_NAME TEXT,
 E_MAIL TEXT NOT NULL,
 COUNTRY TEXT,
 STATE TEXT,
 CITY TEXT,
 ADDRESS TEXT,
 STATUS INTEGER,
 SECURITY_QUESTION TEXT,
 SECURITY_ANSWER TEXT,
 LAST_PASSWD_RESET DATE,
 DESCRIPTION TEXT,
 LAST_UPDATED DATE,
 CREATED DATE
)
;

-- ADD KEYS FOR TABLE ACCOUNT

ALTER TABLE ACCOUNT ADD CONSTRAINT KEY1 PRIMARY KEY (ID)
;

ALTER TABLE ACCOUNT ADD CONSTRAINT USER_NAME UNIQUE (USER_NAME)
;

ALTER TABLE ACCOUNT ADD CONSTRAINT E_MAIL UNIQUE (E_MAIL)
;

-- TABLE ACCOUNT_ROLE

CREATE TABLE ACCOUNT_ROLE(
 ID INTEGER NOT NULL,
 USER_NAME TEXT NOT NULL,
 ROLE INTEGER,
 PERMISSION TEXT,
 LAST_UPDATED DATE,
 CREATED DATE
)
;

-- CREATE INDEXES FOR TABLE ACCOUNT_ROLE

CREATE INDEX IX_RELATIONSHIP19 ON ACCOUNT_ROLE (ID)
;

-- ADD KEYS FOR TABLE ACCOUNT_ROLE

ALTER TABLE ACCOUNT_ROLE ADD CONSTRAINT KEY26 PRIMARY KEY (ID)
;

ALTER TABLE ACCOUNT_ROLE ADD CONSTRAINT RELATIONSHIP19 FOREIGN KEY (ID) REFERENCES ACCOUNT (ID) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE
;
```

What join query I need to use in order to get the result with proper ID?
As you can see I use ID as primary key in both tables with cascade delete.

Comment: Do you want to select all users and their accounts? Also, the ACCOUNT_ROLE table should have ACCOUNT_NAME column, shouldn't it?

Comment: You've got 2 tables both with a column called Id and no obvious relation between both. Need more information Peter.

Comment: @MikhailChibel yes, can you also show me that please?

Comment: @AshwinNair I updated the post with complete code.

Answer (score 2):

It looks like you just want a simple join

```
select A.*,R.* from Account A inner join Account_Role R on 
A.Id = R.Id
```

You can select the columns you need by modifying the above query as follows:

```
select A.ID A.USER_NAME, A.PASSWD TEXT, A.FIRST_NAME TEXT, --and so on
R.Id, R.User_name, R.Role_Integer --and so on 
from Account A inner join Account_Role R on 
A.Id = R.Id
```

Comment: I get ERROR:  syntax error at or near "."
LINE 1: select A.ID A.USER_NAME, A.PASSWD TEXT, A.FIRST_NAME TEXT, -...

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT * FROM ACCOUNT_ROLE INNER JOIN ACCOUNT ON ACCOUNT.ID=ACCOUNT_ROLE.ID
```

By the way, don't save password as a clear text in the database. Use some sort of hashing. Also, having both tables linked by primary keys is not a good design.

Comment: I get `Caused by: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: ORDER BY "id" is ambiguous`

Comment: Are you using an `Order by ` clause? If so, you need to qualify it. e.g.: `order by Account.Id`

Comment: Peter, you better read sql for beginners first. https://www.google.co.nz/url?sa=t&source=web&rct=j&url=http://www.w3schools.com/sql/&ved=0ahUKEwiZ_OzuuJrNAhVBMaYKHelVCP8QFggsMAM&usg=AFQjCNF2-zIxgQyzqwxy2j7n29JyngSdWg

Comment: Yes, I tried this `SELECT * FROM ACCOUNT_ROLE INNER JOIN ACCOUNT ON ACCOUNT.ID = ACCOUNT_ROLE.ID ORDER BY Account.%S Account.%S offset ? limit ?` But I get Caused by: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: syntax error at or near "Account"
  Position: 99 What is the proper way to use ORDER BY?